# How to calculate thermal resistance when I have two metal sections as shown below?

Tags: heatsink

I have to calculate the Thermal Resistance of the heat-sink which as below.

[image]

The ICs top is first first connected to a solid piece of Aluminum and then that solid Aluminum is connected to top plate of the Unit.

In this case, how to calculate the thermal resistance of the "Solid piece of Aluminum + top plate"?

Even some pointers to any reference design will help.

Thanks.

Comment: You **calculate** it with a tedious 3D integral. You **approximate** it by taking crude 2D approximations and using conductivity formulae. So model the first alli block as a semi-cylinder, and break that into a few shells, which you then treat as blocks with average area and thickness. Treat the top plate as an annulus, around the circular approximation of its junction to the first block. I'd expect the exact and the approxmiate results to be within a factor of 2 of each other. How are the two pieces of alli joined together?

Comment: We are going to use -SCREW- between those two pieces. 
Thank you for giving the 'first principles' way of analysis. It is looking very complicated for me. Do you know any free-software where I can get reasonable results?